# Android Studio 1.3 Preview NDK support

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

Yesterday [Google announced](http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2015/05/android-m-developer-preview-tools.html) that native code debugging is now possible with this version of Android Studio.

https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/2Gk6yrZKV4X

I've updated to the newest build version "AI-141.1962279" and can't see any possibility of debugging native code.

I've switched to build-tools 23.0-rc1, used gradle plugin 1.3.0-beta1 but cannot set breakpoints in native code or step into JNI calls.

Is it really working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**July 10th update** Android Studio Preview with NDK support is available : https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview

---

Android Studio 1.3.0-Preview is indeed available through the Android Studio "Check for updates" menu.

Unfortunately, all C++ features aren't available yet in this preview. They will be available in about 2 weeks.

Source : [Google IO dev tools keynote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7ihSQ44WO0) at 35:38

Comment: June 19th update (as highlighted by @oamrani below): "1.3 Beta is now available in the beta channel! Sorry, this build does not yet contain the C/C++ support;"   Seems this link is the place to check latest status: http://tools.android.com/recent

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio 1.3 Beta Available
posted Jun 19, 2015, 11:37 AM by Tor Norbye
Android Studio 1.3 Beta is now available in the beta channel! ***Sorry, this build does not yet contain the C/C++ support***; we are still ironing out a couple of critical issues, but we hope to be ready in the next week or two. Similarly, the vector rasterization support is also still not enabled due to various bugs.

UPDATE:
the 9th of July update contains c++ debug
http://tools.android.com/recent

Comment: finally c++ debug support on RC1

Answer (score 0):

Even on the [Canary Channel](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary), the latest currenlty available build is 1.2.1.1. We will simply have to wait a bit longer for 1.3. The "About Box" in Android Studio also displays the version number; check that to be sure.

Comment: When I open the updates dialog the current version for me is 1.3

Comment: No way, in about box it says "built on May, 27" and in Updates windows it states Android Studio 1.3

Comment: If so, I want it too :-) Where did you download it?

Comment: Files->Settings->Update in AStudio and choose Canary chanell as update source. But no idea how to debug c++ in 1.3! It doesn't step into native functions.

Comment: you have switch to canary channel and update to this version but my about shows build version instead of "Android Studio 1.3"

Comment: Also unable to see 1.3. I have been using the canary channel for a while, but I only see 1.2.1.1 on the download page. Also, the canary build list page doesn't seem to have 1.3 listed: http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary

Comment: What do you mean? What stuff? "This build contains only bug fixes relative to preview 3."

Answer (score 0):

"As announced at Google I/O, Android Studio 1.3 will include C/C++ support as well, but that is not included in the first couple of preview builds."

Source: 
https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/androidstudio13preview1available

Answer (score 0):

FYI:

NDK support is included from Android Studio 1.3 RC1 on.  This includes editing running and debugging C and C++ code.  See [Android NDK Preview](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview) and [experimental Gradle plugin guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental).

Answer (score 0):

with Android Studio [1.4 release](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio14beta3available) you could debug native JNI code.  Your project need to use gradle plugin [com.android.model.application](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-experimental) though.

- After you create a project with JNI code in it, this Android Studio version will create a debug Configuration (mine is called app-native)
- once you select this configuration, you could set breakpoint in JNI code
- then run your app with android studio [it will download and start app on device]
- When JNI code is launched, Android Studio will break right away. You could set more breakpoint at this moment too
- Then let debugger "go" [to continue ]
- Your breakpoints will get hit

The gradle model plugin examples could be found from googlesamples/android-ndk on github. There is a youtube clip called HelloJniWithAndroidStudio shows how to create a hello-jni with android studio 1.3, most steps still work for 1.4 -- it might help for build.gradle creation.

Different version of gradle mode plugin requires different gradle version:

- Gradle-Model-Plugin-version 0.2.0 works with Gradle Version 2.5
- Gradle-Model-Plugin-version 0.3.0-alpha3 works with Gradle version 2.6
  you could find out what versions are available from the jcenter links mentioned earlier.